# Oracle Connection not found when deploying an ssis package from SSIS 2019 to Sql Server

Tags: oracle, azure, visual-studio, ssis

Azure SQL Database
VS Studio 2019
Latest version of SSDT

I have an SSIS package that is loading data from an oracle db to SQL server using the Microsoft Oracle Connector in SSIS.
The package runs just fine in SSIS and the data is loaded fast ; but when I deploy the package to SQL Server (which is an Azure SQL db), I get the following Errors  :

> Load:Error: The component metadata for "Oracle Source, clsid
> {8DC69D45-2AD5-40C6-AAEC-25722F92D6FC}" could not be upgraded to the
> newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.
>
> Load_Test:Error: The connection
> "{70AFF065-3E14-43F1-AF76-52BBF3BCDA95}" is not found. This error is
> thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element
> is not found.
>
> Load:Error: Cannot find the connection manager with ID
> "{70AFF065-3E14-43F1-AF76-52BBF3BCDA95}" in the connection manager
> collection due to error code 0xC0010009. That connection manager is
> needed by "Oracle Source.Connections[ORACLEConnection]" in the
> connection manager collection of "Oracle Source". Verify that a
> connection manager in the connection manager collection, Connections,
> has been created with that ID.
>
> Load_Test:Error: The connection
> "{70AFF065-3E14-43F1-AF76-52BBF3BCDA95}" is not found. This error is
> thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element
> is not found.

Any insight ?

tried to google as much as possible

Comment: There's no screenshot - please post that actual text. Most likely you need to install oarcle drivers in the SSIS runtime, which I assume is probably ADF? Where you deploy and where you execute are two different things

Comment: Are you executing on an ADF runtime? If so is this your error? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/607650/azure-data-factory-oracle-connection-through-self

Comment: sorry for some reason the screenshot did not get posted.  I just copied and pasted all the message errors in the post.
I deployed directly into the SQL Server so I am not going through the ADF.
I execute the package directly in SQL server just to test it out before I can trigger it from the ADF.
I right click on the package and click on execute. 
Here are the message errors I get :
The component metadata for "Oracle Destination" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component
This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found

Comment: Please log into the Azure SQL Server and type `SELECT @@VERSION` it's still not clear what you're deploying to and where your packages are running

Comment: When you say _he package runs just fine in SSIS_ do you mean it runs fine inside the SSIS development tool, i.e. Visual Studio? Please post the version of VS.

Comment: Hi Nick 
Correct, the package runs fine in VS.
SQL Server Version :
VS Studio Version : VS 2019 version 16.11.24
SQL Server : Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Comment: To be clear, Azure SQL has the "package" store but it doesn't actually run the package. Whatever you are running the package in needs Oracle drviers installed